# How to import only one specific package from module to avoid 65k issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-proguard

I have several modules in project (A, B, C). Module B is using by another modules. In result I'm getting 65k method limit issue.

So. Is there a way to import only specific packages from module B to module A? May it can be realized using proguard?

Answer (score 0):

I think, there's an easier solution (not better though):

1. You can use multidex option in your build configuraion. See [google doc](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)
2. If you are using play services, you can use only those you really need since they have been divided into separate [services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is use only needed libraries, search for alternative libraries that has lower method count. For example Picasso library uses less than 1k methods, Glide around 4k but it has more features.

For Google services use granular dependency - import only needed ones.

You can repackage existing libraries, just get needed features or just search for particular class in github repository

Proguard will strip unused classes.

Multidex is your last resort - for minSdk lower than 21 your build time will increase. I'm switching to minSdk 21 when working on code (it builds a lot faster)  and going back to target minSdk when testing. Still you shouldn't be scared by multidex, when you will work on big project that has a lot of views and features, you will need get used to it.